# Grouping tuples within a lists

Tags: python, tuples, defaultdict

I have a set of tuples within a list in which I am trying to group the similar items together.
Eg.

```
[('/Desktop/material_design_segment/arc_01.texture', 'freshnel_intensity_3.0022.jpg'),
 ('/Desktop/material_design_segment/arc_01.texture', 'freshnel_intensity_4.0009.jpg'),
 ('/Desktop/material_design_segment/arc_08.texture', 'freshnel_intensity_8.0020.jpg'),
 ('/Desktop/material_design_segment/arc_05.texture', 'freshnel_intensity_5.0009.jpg'),
 ('/Desktop/material_design_filters/custom/phase_03.texture', 'rounded_viscosity.0002.jpg'),
 ('/Desktop/material_design_filters/custom/phase_03.texture', 'freshnel_intensity_9.0019.jpg')]
```

My results should return me:

```
'/Desktop/material_design_segment/arc_01.texture':
    'freshnel_intensity_3.0022.jpg',
    'freshnel_intensity_4.0009.jpg',
'/Desktop/material_design_segment/arc_08.texture':
    'freshnel_intensity_8.0020.jpg'
'/Desktop/material_design_segment/arc_05.texture':
    'freshnel_intensity_5.0009.jpg'
'/Desktop/material_design_filters/custom/phase_03.texture':
    'rounded_viscosity.0002.jpg',
    'freshnel_intensity_9.0019.jpg'
```

However, when I tried using my code as follows, it only returns me 1 item.

```
groups = defaultdict(str)
for date, value in aaa:
    groups[date] = value

pprint(groups)
```

This is the ouput:

```
{'/Desktop/material_design_segment/arc_01.texture': 'freshnel_intensity_4.0009.jpg'
 '/Desktop/material_design_filters/custom/phase_03.texture': 'freshnel_intensity_9.0019.jpg'
 '/Desktop/material_design_segment/arc_08.texture': 'freshnel_intensity_8.0020.jpg'
 '/Desktop/material_design_segment/arc_05.texture': 'freshnel_intensity_5.0009.jpg'}
```

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Your expected result isn't real Python. Perhaps try `defaultdict(list)`, and *add* rather than *replace*.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning `value` to `groups[date]`, which overwrites the previous value. You need to append it to a list.

```
groups = defaultdict(list)
for date, value in aaa:
    groups[date].append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append the values into a list as follows (based on your code):

```
groups = defaultdict(list)
for date, value in aaa:
    groups[date].append(value)

print(groups)
```